# How to exclude the id in My Store procedure, when status change

Tags: mysql

I am suffering from this concept
Here there is table which have two columns Name HEADERID and STATUS. When the status is delivered.That id Should not Show

My Table
[image]

Output should be like this
[image]

Please any one answer

Answer (score -3, accepted):

STEP 1: Need to create the 1 temporary table take the distinct header id from the table and
insert into this temporary table
Step 2: use while loop to filter each data and create another temporary table and insert
that data using header id
Step 3 : Finally create select query to display the data.

Example code:[image: Example code]

Comment: Thank you mam, My issue was fixed

Comment: please don't post image with code

Comment: Also, there's no need to create a temporary table for such a basic query. And row-by-row aka slow-by-slow processing *really* isn't needed for such a basic query.

Answer (score 0):

The following (untested) should work for you:

```
select *
from my_table x
where not exists (
  select null
  from my_table
  where header_id = x.header_id
  and status = 'Delivered'
);
```